# Jupyter Notebook Doesnt open

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

Im having troubles opening Jupyter or Anaconda Navigator.

Each time I click on the shortcut, the kernel black window opens and closes so fast that I just cant see what it shows and nothing happens.

In case of Anaconda Navigator, the black window appears and closes twice and nothing happens either.

Hope you can help me.

I already tried uninstalling and reinstalling. I wanted to do it again but now the Anaconda Uninstaller doesnt appear :(

Answer (score 0):

did you try running it from the command line ? (cmd/bash)
You can use the command `jupyter notebook` and it should normally lunch the notebook if everything is correctly installed.